# Not able to play a video clearly on ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, video, flash, mplayer

I have downloaded a video from youtube using the ubuntu command-line (Virtual PC)

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl youtube-dl http:<url>
```

I am trying to play a video after installing

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

I issued below the command

```
mplayer -vo caca VLHJUfgxEO4.mp4
```

It is playing a video , but the video is not clear. Some ascii characters are displaying.

How can I view the video clearly?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Have you tried a different video player? Or not running it from the terminal, does it still happen?

Answer (score 4):

You are asking mplayer to output in color ascii characters with the `-vo caca` parameter.

Try playing your video with just the command:

```
mplayer VLHJUfgxEO4.mp4
```

Mplayer will then play the video normally in a video window (provided that you are running X).

However, if you want to play your video file without running X, you could try using the following command:

```
mplayer -vo fbdev2 -fs VLHJUfgxEO4.mp4
```

For full screen zooming:

```
mplayer -vo fbdev2 -zoom VLHJUfgxEO4.mp4
```