# play video on ubuntu server

Tags: server, xorg, remote-access, video-player, remote-x-session

I have ubuntu server running, no xorg,x11,desktop. There are some videos in the server hdd. On a remote machine I can access them using samba or plex. The server machine has its own monitor+audio (its a complete desktop). Is there a way I can use the client machine as a kind of remote to play some videos on server machine(which are in server hdd). The requirement is to use some ssh command and video start playing on server machine (it would be way cool if i can control it as well play pause volume etc), i should be able to close the ssh connection and video continue to play.

Comment: Try the second command from [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/355489/216503)

Comment: @heemayl I believe I didn't put my question right. I have an external desktop which is running ubuntu server, what I want is fire a command over ssh which make the ubuntu server to start a video over connected monitor.I don't want to run anything within the client machine(it can although act as a remote, if it can?). With the command suggested in post I am getting some error and need some help in figuring it out

Comment: Error opening/initializing the selected video_out (-vo) device.
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'....
[AO_ALSA] Playback open error: No such file or directory
[AO OSS] audio_setup: Can't open audio device /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
[JACK] cannot open server
[AO SDL] Unsupported audio format: 0x1d.
[AO SDL] Unable to open audio: No available audio device
Video: no video

Comment: It would be great if you [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/593189/edit) and clarify it more with whatever info you have..

Comment: @heemayl I updated the question, hopefully its clear. If not please suggest appropriate edits. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tryed to use this ??
% sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
or this 
% apt-get install miro

i think if you was connecting with internet your problem will fixed  :D

Comment: I have vlc +browser plugin installed and did install Xserver binaries,but vlc is opened in command line mode. When I invoke vlc abc.avi it start showing lots of dots on black screen not audio/video though.